# Qiskit : how to reset all variables in a simulation

Tags: qiskit

I have a simple qiskit circuit :

```
import qiskit

def TestA():
 qr=qiskit.QuantumRegister(5)
 cr=qiskit.ClassicalRegister(4)
 qc=qiskit.QuantumCircuit(qr,cr)
 qc.h(0)
 qc.cx(0,4)
 qc.h(1)
 qc.cz(1,0)
 qc.measure([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3])
 print(qc)
```

If I run TestA more than once it seems that some variables are not cleared.
For example :

```
>>> import Tests
>>> Tests.TestA()
      ┌───┐           ┌─┐
q0_0: ┤ H ├─────■───■─┤M├───
      ├───┤     │   │ └╥┘┌─┐
q0_1: ┤ H ├─────┼───■──╫─┤M├
      └┬─┬┘     │      ║ └╥┘
q0_2: ─┤M├──────┼──────╫──╫─
       └╥┘ ┌─┐  │      ║  ║
q0_3: ──╫──┤M├──┼──────╫──╫─
        ║  └╥┘┌─┴─┐    ║  ║
q0_4: ──╫───╫─┤ X ├────╫──╫─
        ║   ║ └───┘    ║  ║
c0: 4/══╩═══╩══════════╩══╩═
        2   3          0  1
>>> Tests.TestA()
      ┌───┐           ┌─┐
q1_0: ┤ H ├─────■───■─┤M├───
      ├───┤     │   │ └╥┘┌─┐
q1_1: ┤ H ├─────┼───■──╫─┤M├
      └┬─┬┘     │      ║ └╥┘
q1_2: ─┤M├──────┼──────╫──╫─
       └╥┘ ┌─┐  │      ║  ║
q1_3: ──╫──┤M├──┼──────╫──╫─
        ║  └╥┘┌─┴─┐    ║  ║
q1_4: ──╫───╫─┤ X ├────╫──╫─
        ║   ║ └───┘    ║  ║
c1: 4/══╩═══╩══════════╩══╩═
        2   3          0  1
>>>
```

The register names in the first run where q0 and c0; in the second run they're changed to q1 and c1. It makes me suspect that other things are also left over from previous runs. Is there a way to reset everything at the beginning of each test?

I see the same behavior if I reload the module (using importlib.reload(Tests))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qiskit just counts the amount of instances of these classes and automatically assigns a default name with the counting in it - you can see that [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py).

If you give names to the registers:

```
qr = qiskit.QuantumRegister(5, name = “reg1”)
cr = qiskit.ClassicalRegister(4, name = “classic_reg”)
```

Then you will see the same name in each iteration.

About that:

> It makes me suspect that other things are also left over from previous runs

If you call to `TestA()` in each iteration then nothing should be left over. In each iteration instances are created as local variables inside the function and they end their life when the execution of the function ends.

Comment: thanks this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `qr=qiskit.QuantumRegister(5)` and `cr=qiskit.ClassicalRegister(4)`, just enter the number qubits and number of classical register explicitly.

```
import qiskit

def TestA():
 qc=qiskit.QuantumCircuit(5,4)
 qc.h(0)
 qc.cx(0,4)
 qc.h(1)
 qc.cz(1,0)
 qc.measure([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3])
 print(qc)

TestA()
```